# Ubuntu Core - Can't resolve hostname

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

Running `snap find ntpserver` I get the following error:

```
error: cannot list snaps: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/search?confinement=strict&fields=anon_download_url%2Carchitecture%2Cchannel%2Cdownload_sha3_384%2Csummary%2Cdescription%2Cdeltas%2Cbinary_filesize%2Cdownload_url%2Cepoch%2Cicon_url%2Clast_updated%2Cpackage_name%2Cprices%2Cpublisher%2Cratings_average%2Crevision%2Cscreenshot_urls%2Csnap_id%2Clicense%2Cbase%2Csupport_url%2Ccontact%2Ctitle%2Ccontent%2Cversion%2Corigin%2Cdeveloper_id%2Cprivate%2Cconfinement%2Cchannel_maps_list&q=ntpserver:
dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io on [::1]:53:
read udp [::1]:43577->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

Also, `ping www.nasa.gov` is failing with `ping: unknown host www.nasa.gov` while `ping [NASA’s IP address]` works fine.

I tried to set `ipv4.dns` setting to `8.8.8.8` using the network-manager [as indicated](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/edit-connections) but the problem is still there.

This wasn't an issue in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was just bad network configuration which was fixed by re-running the network setup configuration:

```
sudo console-conf
```